# Adding smooth scrolling using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm fairly new to coding and looking to create a smooth animation between my anchor points. I don't mind if this is with JavaScript or JQuery, however I'm new to both so I may not understand.

I've tried this code (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) both JavaScript and JQuery and neither worked for some reason.
**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="tab1">
    <a class="link1" href="#home">
        <div class="text1">Home</div>
    </a></div>
    <div class="tab2">
    <a class="link2" href="#work">
        <div class="text2">Work</div>
    </a></div>
    <div class="tab3">
    <a class="link3" href="#about">
        <div class="text3">About</div>
    </a></div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="fullscreen">

    <div class="box home" id="home">

    <div class="heading">
        <h1>Hi,</h1>
        <h2>I'm Nathan Wilson</h2>
        <h3>a Graphic Designer based in Nottingham, U.K.</h3>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box work" id="work">

    </div>
    <div class="box about" id="about">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've removed any Javascript i've tried, and will try with any suggestions I receive.
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzjBqK

Comment: @RickSibley I've just tried this, changing 'left-side-nav' to 'navbar' and no luck unfortunately, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This code works, I've used that CSS tricks code alot, so this makes me think that you are not loading jQuery before running your script. Here's a pen:
https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/NoRBwd

On your page make sure you are loading Jquery (I'd recommend loading the google version) and then load another js file with a $(document).ready(function() { // Your Code Here });

Comment: In my answer I change it to navbar and it works

Comment: @NeilWkz I have added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>` in to the top of my HTML and created a separate JS file, updated it on the original post but still doesnt work.

Comment: @NathanWilson cool, so jquery is the dependency if your page loads that first, then it runs script.js it should work with the CSS tricks code above. If you're still having issues look in the console, and see what the error message is.

Comment: @NeilWkz Still no luck, it's showing in the sources that the js script and the jquery from google are both there - No errors shown on the console.

Comment: @NathanWilson and when you click you the link I guess you'll get the default behaviour jumping directly to the section, if you're not getting any errors in the console I'm not sure what else to suggest. If it's easier maybe try and download the export of my codepen and try to compare it to the code you have: https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/share/zip/NoRBwd

Answer (score 0):

I've taken my comment and made it simpler. Removed some fluff. This is smooth scrolling achieved through JQuery.

```js
$("a").on('click', function(event) {
  if (this.hash !== "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 1200, function() {
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #c62334;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="fullscreen">

    <div class="box home" id="home">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>
        Cake halvah brownie. Croissant pudding macaroon danish marzipan. Brownie oat cake muffin. Candy canes candy canes jelly-o. Dragée jelly carrot cake. Carrot cake chocolate croissant marshmallow. Sweet roll caramels danish liquorice. Pie bonbon soufflé
        powder marshmallow halvah topping marzipan bonbon. Muffin gingerbread gummi bears jelly beans muffin tart. Macaroon pastry cheesecake jelly beans caramels brownie sugar plum cheesecake. Brownie cake brownie lemon drops cake fruitcake sesame snaps.
        Wafer ice cream wafer cupcake lollipop.</p>

      <div class="heading">
        <h1>your</h1>
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>here</h3>
      </div>

      <p>Macaroon sweet roll icing tart icing carrot cake jelly pastry jujubes. Gingerbread tart bonbon cheesecake macaroon cookie. Biscuit cookie sweet roll jelly beans bonbon. Sugar plum chocolate cake donut candy lollipop caramels cheesecake croissant
        cookie. Apple pie cake topping cotton candy sweet. Dessert muffin muffin pudding tootsie roll brownie chocolate bar croissant. Jujubes sugar plum gummies chocolate tart danish. Fruitcake cookie jelly-o cake powder powder cookie ice cream. Cupcake
        chocolate lollipop jelly ice cream pastry chupa chups. Gummi bears marzipan sugar plum jujubes marshmallow tiramisu pie. Chupa chups chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Soufflé sesame snaps carrot cake marshmallow. Danish lemon drops ice cream bear
        claw croissant.</p>

    </div>



    <div class="box work" id="work">
      <h1>Work</h1>
      <p>
        Cake halvah brownie. Croissant pudding macaroon danish marzipan. Brownie oat cake muffin. Candy canes candy canes jelly-o. Dragée jelly carrot cake. Carrot cake chocolate croissant marshmallow. Sweet roll caramels danish liquorice. Pie bonbon soufflé
        powder marshmallow halvah topping marzipan bonbon. Muffin gingerbread gummi bears jelly beans muffin tart. Macaroon pastry cheesecake jelly beans caramels brownie sugar plum cheesecake. Brownie cake brownie lemon drops cake fruitcake sesame snaps.
        Wafer ice cream wafer cupcake lollipop.</p>

      <p>Macaroon sweet roll icing tart icing carrot cake jelly pastry jujubes. Gingerbread tart bonbon cheesecake macaroon cookie. Biscuit cookie sweet roll jelly beans bonbon. Sugar plum chocolate cake donut candy lollipop caramels cheesecake croissant
        cookie. Apple pie cake topping cotton candy sweet. Dessert muffin muffin pudding tootsie roll brownie chocolate bar croissant. Jujubes sugar plum gummies chocolate tart danish. Fruitcake cookie jelly-o cake powder powder cookie ice cream. Cupcake
        chocolate lollipop jelly ice cream pastry chupa chups. Gummi bears marzipan sugar plum jujubes marshmallow tiramisu pie. Chupa chups chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Soufflé sesame snaps carrot cake marshmallow. Danish lemon drops ice cream bear
        claw croissant.</p>

    </div>

    <div  class="box about" id="about">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>
        Cake halvah brownie. Croissant pudding macaroon danish marzipan. Brownie oat cake muffin. Candy canes candy canes jelly-o. Dragée jelly carrot cake. Carrot cake chocolate croissant marshmallow. Sweet roll caramels danish liquorice. Pie bonbon soufflé
        powder marshmallow halvah topping marzipan bonbon. Muffin gingerbread gummi bears jelly beans muffin tart. Macaroon pastry cheesecake jelly beans caramels brownie sugar plum cheesecake. Brownie cake brownie lemon drops cake fruitcake sesame snaps.
        Wafer ice cream wafer cupcake lollipop.</p>

      <p>Macaroon sweet roll icing tart icing carrot cake jelly pastry jujubes. Gingerbread tart bonbon cheesecake macaroon cookie. Biscuit cookie sweet roll jelly beans bonbon. Sugar plum chocolate cake donut candy lollipop caramels cheesecake croissant
        cookie. Apple pie cake topping cotton candy sweet. Dessert muffin muffin pudding tootsie roll brownie chocolate bar croissant. Jujubes sugar plum gummies chocolate tart danish. Fruitcake cookie jelly-o cake powder powder cookie ice cream. Cupcake
        chocolate lollipop jelly ice cream pastry chupa chups. Gummi bears marzipan sugar plum jujubes marshmallow tiramisu pie. Chupa chups chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Soufflé sesame snaps carrot cake marshmallow. Danish lemon drops ice cream bear
        claw croissant.</p>

      <p>Macaroon sweet roll icing tart icing carrot cake jelly pastry jujubes. Gingerbread tart bonbon cheesecake macaroon cookie. Biscuit cookie sweet roll jelly beans bonbon. Sugar plum chocolate cake donut candy lollipop caramels cheesecake croissant
        cookie. Apple pie cake topping cotton candy sweet. Dessert muffin muffin pudding tootsie roll brownie chocolate bar croissant. Jujubes sugar plum gummies chocolate tart danish. Fruitcake cookie jelly-o cake powder powder cookie ice cream. Cupcake
        chocolate lollipop jelly ice cream pastry chupa chups. Gummi bears marzipan sugar plum jujubes marshmallow tiramisu pie. Chupa chups chupa chups candy canes jujubes. Soufflé sesame snaps carrot cake marshmallow. Danish lemon drops ice cream bear
        claw croissant.</p>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```